# Android Studio Emulator Error (Intel HAXM is Required / No Emulator Installed)

Tags: android, android-emulator

I just updated my Android API to 25, and my emulators have since stopped working. When I try to run my emulator, it gives me the error "Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD. No emulator installed. Please Download the emulator" as a popup (shown below) and the `Event Log` prints out "Error running app: This version of Android Studio is incompatible with the Gradle Plugin used. Try disabling Instant Run (or updating either the IDE or the Gradle plugin to the latest version)".

What I am confused about is that I have turned off Instant Run via settings and I have downloaded the Intel x86 Emulator in SDK Tools.

Error:
[image]

SDK Manager: 
[image]

Instant Run:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SDK manager only downloads the Intel HAXM installer, but does not do the actual application installation in many cases.

Go to `{SDK location}/sdk/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/` and run the MSI installer from there.

Additionally you have to enable VTX extensions in your BIOS on the computer.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution works for me is...

1. Goto your SDK folder location and delete "emulator" and "system-images" folder.
2. Open android studio -> Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager
3. Switch to SDK Tools tab check Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) click OK
4. After successfully installing HAXM goto Android Studio -> Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager Delete all previous emulators and create new AVD.

Answer (score 0):

Install this and try to run again.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I believe that is the same thing that I posted a picture of. If I am wrong, please let me know, however, I believe it is already installed.

Comment: Create virtual AVD and install necessary file from Android Sdk manager for emulator .

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that Hyper-V was not uninstalled even when I removed it from installed windows components. I got this from:
https://github.com/intel/haxm/blob/master/docs/manual-windows.md

> Certain advanced Windows 10 features, such as Device Guard (in particular, Hypervisor-protected code integrity or HVCI) and Credential Guard, can prevent Hyper-V from being completely disabled. In other words, when any of these features are enabled, so is Hyper-V, even though Windows may report otherwise.

Helpfully, it says how to solve it, and it worked for me after two days of frustration:

> The Device Guard and Credential Guard hardware readiness tool released by Microsoft can disable the said Windows 10 features along with Hyper-V:

1. Download the latest version of the tool from here. The following steps assume version 3.6.
2. Unzip.
3. Open an elevated (i.e. Run as administrator) Command Prompt.
4. @powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Command "X:\path\to\dgreadiness_v3.6\DG_Readiness_Tool_v3.6.ps1 -Disable"
5. Reboot.

This disables Device Guard and Credential Guard and allows HAXM to get control of virtualization. After the reboot, HAXM should install from the Android SDK manager without issue. Good luck.