# Emulator error for Android studio

Tags: emulation

I had this problem when updating to Android studio 2.3. The emulator does not work even though my testers are installed. How can I get rid of this fault?enter image description here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHBRX.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Emulator Error (Intel HAXM is Required / No Emulator Installed)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181450/android-studio-emulator-error-intel-haxm-is-required-no-emulator-installed)

Comment: The emulator is installed but still has a problem(install emulator)

Answer (score 0):

If your emulator has Android 6.0 marshmallow then allow required permission by moving your app icon to app info.